# alpine linux sys mode install on raspberry pi

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

I'm working with the armhf release of alpinelinux from https://www.alpinelinux.org/downloads/ on a raspberry pi 3b. I've installed a desktop extension card from https://www.newark.com/element14/pi-desktop/accessory-type-desktop-computer/dp/05AC3756?st=raspberry%20pi%20desktop with a 500GB SSD. I've enabled the proper OTP bit to permit booting from the SSD. I expanded the distribution tar file onto the SSD. This boots just fine, but only to a tmpfs file system. Among other things, the setup-alpine script is supposed to permanently move / to the SSD, but this doesn't work. The culprit appears to be in the setup-disk subscript; seems it was never updated to deal with the armhf architecture or the vmlinux bootloader. Has anyone found a corrected setup-disk script or otherwise made my desired configuration work? Thanks.

Comment: You do not mention the version you have tried, but now alpine supports Raspberry Pi 3b.

Comment: Have you tried to follow this guide, perhaps? https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Persistent_storage